# Supervised Time Series efficiency improvement

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, xgboost

The data that I have is hourly recorded over the past 4 months. I am building a time series model and I've tried several methods so far: Arima, LSTMs, Prophet but they can be quite slow for my task since I have to run the model on thousands of time series in different locations. So then I thought it might be interesting to transform it into a supervised problem and use regression.

I extracted 4 features from the univariate time series and its time index, namely: dayofweek, hour, daily average and hourly average. So at the moment I am using these 4 predictors but could possibly extract more(like beginning of the day, noon, etc-also if you have any other suggestions here they are very welcomed :) )

I've used XGBoost for the regression and here are parts of the code:

```
# XGB
import xgboost as xgb 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# Functions needed 
def convert_dates(x):
        x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['date'])
        #x['month'] = x['date'].dt.month
        #x['year'] = x['date'].dt.year
        x['dayofweek'] = x['date'].dt.dayofweek
        x['hour'] = x['date'].dt.hour
        #x['week_no'] = pd.to_numeric(x['date'].index.strftime("%V"))
        x.pop('date')
        return(x)

def add_avg(x):
        x['daily_avg']=x.groupby(['dayofweek'])['y'].transform('mean')
        x['hourly_avg'] = x.groupby(['dayofweek','hour'])['y'].transform('mean')
        #x['monthly_avg']=x.groupby(['month'])['y'].transform('mean')
        #x['weekly_avg']=x.groupby(['week_no'])['y'].transform('mean')
        return x

xgb_mape_r2_dict = {}
```

I then run a for loop in which I select a location and build the model for it. Here I split the data into a train and test part. I knew there might be problems due to the Easter holidays in my country last week because those are rare events so that is why I split the training and test data in that manner. So I actually consider the data from the beginning of the year up to two weeks ago as training data and the very next week after that as test data.

```
for j in range(10,20):
    data = df_all.loc[df_all['Cell_Id']==top_cells[j]]
    data.drop(['Cell_Id', 'WDay'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    data['date'] = data.index
    period = 168
    data_train = data.iloc[:-2*period,:]
    data_test = data.iloc[-2*period:-period,:]


    data_train = convert_dates(data_train)
    data_test = convert_dates(data_test)
    data_train.columns = ['y', 'dayofweek', 'hour']
    data_test.columns = ['y', 'dayofweek', 'hour']

    data_train = add_avg(data_train)
    daily_avg = data_train.groupby(['dayofweek'])['y'].mean().reset_index()
    hourly_avg = data_train.groupby(['dayofweek', 'hour'])['y'].mean().reset_index()
```

Now, for the test data I add the past averages, namely the 7 daily averages from the past and the 168 hourly averages from the past as well. This is actually the part that takes the longest amount of time to run and I would like to improve its efficiency.

```
    value_dict ={}
    for k in range(168):
        value_dict[tuple(hourly_avg.iloc[k])[:2]] = tuple(hourly_avg.iloc[k])[2]


    data_test['daily_avg'] = 0
    data_test['hourly_avg'] = 0
    for i in range(len(data_test)):
        data_test['daily_avg'][i] = daily_avg['y'][data_test['dayofweek'][i]]
        data_test['hourly_avg'][i] = value_dict[(data_test['dayofweek'][i], data_test['hour'][i])]
```

My current run time is of 30 seconds for every iteration in the for loop which is way too slow because of the poor way that I use to add the averages in the test data. I would really appreciate if anyone could point out how could I implement this bit faster.

I will also add the rest of my code and make some other observations as well:

```
    x_train = data_train.drop('y',axis=1)
    x_test = data_test.drop('y',axis=1)
    y_train = data_train['y']
    y_test = data_test['y']

    def XGBmodel(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test):
        matrix_train = xgb.DMatrix(x_train,label=y_train)
        matrix_test = xgb.DMatrix(x_test,label=y_test)
        model=xgb.train(params={'objective':'reg:linear','eval_metric':'mae'}
                        ,dtrain=matrix_train,num_boost_round=500, 
                        early_stopping_rounds=20,evals=[(matrix_test,'test')],)
        return model

    model=XGBmodel(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test)


    #submission = pd.DataFrame(x_pred.pop('id'))
    y_pred = model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(x_test), ntree_limit = model.best_ntree_limit)

    #submission['sales']= y_pred

    y_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred)
    y_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
    y_test.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
    compare_df = pd.concat([y_test, y_pred], axis = 1)
    compare_df.columns = ['Real', 'Predicted']
    compare_df.plot()

    mape = (np.abs((y_test['y'] - y_pred[0])/y_test['y']).mean())*100
    r2 = r2_score(y_test['y'], y_pred[0])
    xgb_mape_r2_dict[top_cells[j]] = [mape,r2]
```

I've used both R-squared and MAPE as accuracy measures although I don't think MAPE is indicated anymore since I've transformed the time series problem into a regression problem. Any thoughts on your part on this subject?

Thank you very much for your time and consideration. Any help is very much appreciated.

Update: I have managed to fix the issue using pandas' merge. I've first created two dataframes containing the daily averges and hourly averages from the training data and then merged these ataframes with the test data:

```
data_test = merge(data_test, daily_avg,['dayofweek'],'daily_avg')
data_test = merge(data_test, hourly_av['dayofweek','hour'],'hourly_avg')
data_test.columns = ['y', 'dayofweek', 'hour', 'daily_avg', 'hourly_avg']
```

where we used the merge function defined as:

```
def merge(x,y,col,col_name):
    x =pd.merge(x, y, how='left', on=None, left_on=col, right_on=col,
            left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
             copy=True, indicator=False,validate=None)
    x=x.rename(columns={'sales':col_name})
    return x
```

I can now run the model for 2000 locations per hour on a laptop with decent results but I will try to improve it while keeping it fast. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: What is the goal of the time series model? To predict the value N days/hours from a given time?

Comment: What kind of data is it? Sales, sensor readings or what?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the problem is, but it seems to be training time? What is the execution time budget for training your model? How often does it need to be updated, and how much data is included in each training run?

Comment: The goal of the model is to forecast the hourly mobile data volume values one week in advance in order to prevent congestion. The problem is that adding the historical averages  columns in the test data takes most of the time. The model then runs instantly after preparing the test data.

Comment: To be more precise, this is the slow part:

Comment: for i in range(len(data_test)):
        data_test['daily_avg'][i] = daily_avg['y'][data_test['dayofweek'][i]]
        data_test['hourly_avg'][i] = value_dict[(data_test['dayofweek'][i], data_test['hour'][i])]                 I mentioned this in the post as well. Thank you very much for your help.